# how can i connect my laravel server?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

C:\Users\karim486\Desktop\laravel\bookstore>php artisan serve

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bindShared()

this problem show my pc . not connected php artisan serve
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfAGx.jpg)
how can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you upgraded to a new Laravel version. Some packages (eg HTML & forms) arn't ready for the newest version. Switch to the package from https://laravelcollective.com/ and it will work again.